# KOHA cURL PHP API Implementation

Tags: php, curl

Trying to use cURL in interfacing a PHP application with Koha, is there a cURL approach on doing this?
Tried the following;

```
<?php

    $url = "http://opac.example.com/api/v1/oauth/token";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "User:Password");
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $data;
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I got a Bye response.

Comment: Whatever else happens, do NOT exchange credentials or tokens over plain http. If you want to do this, you really need to get https working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution, to anyone who may encounter the same problem:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
      CURLOPT_URL => "http://opac.example.com/api/v1/oauth/token",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=yourcliedid&client_secret=yoursecretkey",//these you generate from your koha account
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ],
    ]);

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    
    $token = $response->access_token;
    
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($token);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```